# Как подключить std::experimental::any?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14

Работаю в MS Visual Studio 2015, набираю в файле исходного кода директиву `#include` `<experimental/...>`, в выпадающем списке нет варианта `any`. Как мне подключить этот хедер? Когда возник этот вопрос, я обошелся версией `any` из фрейморка Boost, сейчас использую Visual Studio 2017. Но в версии студии 2015 я так и не нашел никакого `any`.

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, с какой версией спецификации языка вы работаете. У вас в заголовке написано С++17. Тогда с чего это вдруг вы ищете `<any>` в `<experimental/...>`? В С++17 `<any>` уже совсем не `<experimental/...>`. Это в С++14 оно `<experimental/...>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В стандарте c++17 это [нужно искать](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) в `<any>` под именем `std::any`.

Answer (score 2):

А вы с какой версией работаете?

В 2015 это точно не реализовано. Или у вас VC++ 2017 RC стоит? в нем просто в `<any>` - см. здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/what-s-new-for-visual-cpp-in-visual-studio